# Why aren't array elements initialized in an enhanced for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

When I use normal for-loop, 

all elements in an array will initialize normally:

```
Object[] objs = new Object[10];
for (int i=0;i<objs.length;i++)
        objs[i] = new Object();
```

But when I use a for-each loop.

the array elements are still `null`, after the loop:

```
Object[] objs = new Object[10];
for (Object obj : objs)
        obj = new Object();
```

I thought `obj` refers to a particular element in an array, 

so if I initialize it, the array element will be initialized as well.

Why isn't that happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I thought obj refers to a particular element in an array, 
>   so if I initialize it, the array element will be initialized as well. 
>   Why isn't that happening?

No, `obj` has the *value* of the array element at the start of the body of the loop. It isn't an *alias* for the array element variable. So a loop like this (for arrays; it's different for iterables):

```
for (Object obj : objs) {
    // Code using obj here
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    Object obj = objs[i];
    // Code using obj here
}
```

See [section 14.14.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) for more details of the exact behaviour of the enhanced for loop.

Comment: Section 14.14.2 tells me nothing about this but your answer is very clear, thanks!

Comment: Just to check, does that still mean methods on `objs[i]` can still be done through `obj` by doing `obj.method()`?  Since `obj` is pointing to `objs[i]`

Comment: @SmRndGuy: What do you mean by "methods ... can still be done"? You can still call methods via the reference, but it won't change the contents of the array.

Comment: I mean is `obj.method()` equivalent to doing `objs[i].method()`?

Comment: @SmRndGuy: Yes, because both have the same value - a reference to an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object[] objs = new Object[10];
for (Object obj : objs)
  obj = new Object();
```

You've created the *space* where the objects will go, but you haven't actually created the objects. This will try to iterate over the objects in the array if they exist (which they don't yet!)

```
Object[] objs = new Object[10];
for (int i=0; i < objs.length; i++)
  objs[i] = new Object();
```

This is different due to the fact that you're just simply counting from 0 to 9, and creating + storing them in the appropriate spot in the array.

Comment: Your answer does not really match with Jon Skeet's answer if I understand correctly.

Comment: He's Jon Skeet. I can't compete with that.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the new value to 'obj' and not to the 'objs' , hence the elements are null. You have to assign the value to objs also:

```
    Object[] objs = new Object[10];
    for (int k = 0; k < objs.length; k++) {
        objs[k] = new Object();
        System.out.println(objs[k]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning new object to array element (Which is a variable that would be a reference to an Object) which can be accessed outside the for loop.

```
Object[] objs = new Object[10];
for (int i=0;i<objs.length;i++)
objs[i] = new Object();
```

But in for each loop you are assigning the new object to the local variable (not array elements)

```
Object[] objs = new Object[10];
for (Object obj : objs){
obj = new Object(); 
}
//obj can not be accessed here
```

and If we talk about this line

```
     for (Object obj : objs){
```

Then its means is that you are taking the value of objs element to the local variable obj, which is null.